# Enviar correo clasificado como importante desde python

Tags: python, email, smtp, mail

Desde python quisiera enviar un correo dandole la clasificación de "importante", que por ejemplo en Outlook llegue el mail con el simbolo ! activado.

Actualmente uso la libreria smtplib, sin embargo, no encuentro algún parámetro que le pueda asignar a la clase para que me clasifique el mail como Urgente o Importante.

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que aparezca el signo de exclamación se le puede poner al mail el *header* "Importance" con el valor de "high" de esta forma:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

message = EmailMessage()
message["From"] = "mimail@example.org"
message["To"] = "otromail@example.org"
message["Subject"] = "Mail con signo de exclamacion"
message["Importance"] = "high"
message.set_content("Contenido del mail")
```